# MongoDB connection from Java: how to configure codecs given connection URI

Tags: java, mongodb

I have Java webapp with connection to MongoDB and utilizing custom codecs to encode/decode domain specific Java POJOs to/from MongoDB documents. Connection URL is provided to application via environment variable. The URL can contain options but per URL format documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/ it is not possible to specify codecs in URL.
So my natural choice would be to use MongoClientOptions builder to combine options from URI and new CodecRegistry with my codecs:

```
MongoClientOptions optsWithCodecs = MongoClientOptions.builder(
    mongoURI.getOptions()).codecRegistry(myCodecRegistry).build();
```

The problem is that MongoClient does not provide constructor that would accept URI and MongoClientOptions, there's constructor that takes just URI:

```
public MongoClient(final MongoClientURI uri) {
    super(uri);
}
```

That makes me parse URI manually duplicating some code from MongoClient private methods and then use one of other constructors accepting options.
I would like to find a better way to configure MongoClient with custom codecs.
I'm using Mongo Java driver version 3.3.0

Answer (score 2):

```
Builder optionsBuilder = MongoClientOptions.builder().codecRegistry(myCodecRegistry);
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(connectionString, optionsBuilder));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```
 MongoClientOptions optsWithCodecs = MongoClientOptions.builder(
 mongoURI.getOptions()).codecRegistry(myCodecRegistry).build();
 MongoClientURI mongoClientUri = new MongoClientURI(uri, optsWithCodecs);
 MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoClientUri);
```